# Explicit npm package versions are more secure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm, versioning

Installing explicit package versions with the flag `--save-exact` is considered to be more secure? I've found a post on a Medium https://medium.com/tkssharma/secure-node-js-apps-7613973b6971 (Go to **Use explicit package versions**) where the author states that it is. He says that by doing `npm update` when having `~` or `^` in our `package.json` we can accidentally update to unstable packages.

Comment: If package uses `semver` then you lose possible bug/security updates (need to check manually). By fixing a version, from security perspective, you do worse than letting minor updates (some may argue stability regarding tests done on a specific version).

Comment: @Xaqron I guess you mean detecting known vulnerabilities? I do have in my pipeline `npm audit` check, so in that case I wouldn't say this is a problem. Even without it, everytime `npm install` runs on your machine then there is a summary of vulnerabilities. Then the article's reasoning doesn't makes sense for me.

Comment: The package maintainer, may even fix a security bug before identified by public and release a patch and by fixing the version you miss such an update. I cannot see how fixing package version secures apps and still can argue for the opposite.

Comment: @Xaqron thanks, completely agree with you.